# how to change color of Backbutton Arrow in react native router flux?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-native

how to change color of Backbutton in react native router flux ?
[image]

I try `backButtonBarStyle` but not working...i cant find any solution.tnx for your helps

```
<Scene key="app"  navigationBarStyle={{backgroundColor: '#1e2226',borderBottomColor:"#1e2226"}}  titleStyle={{color : "#FFF"}}>
    <Scene  key="welcome" component={LauchContainer} title="Welcome" />
    <Scene key="ProductDetail"  backButtonBarStyle={{color : "#FFF"}} component={ProductDetail} />
  </Scene>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the documentation it looks like you should be using `backButtonTextStyle` or use `backButtonImage` to use a different icon image

[Check it out here](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md#navigation-bar-back-button)

**Update:**

You can change the colour of the image by setting the `tintColor` in the `leftButtonIconStyle` prop

Comment: Tnx for your answer...but I want change color of arrow without change Image...this is possible?

Comment: ah ok, try using `leftButtonIconStyle` instead and add `tintColor: "red"` to it

Comment: Awesome! May want to accept this answer so that others know that it worked! ;)

Answer (score 1):

add these two line inside the scenes `backButtonTintColor = '#000' leftButtonStyle = {{color : '#000',tintColor : '#000'}}`

as follows

```
<Scene
          key="Scene Key"
          component={Scene Component}
          title="Your title"
          backButtonTextStyle = {{color:'#000000'}}
          barButtonIconStyle={{ tintColor: '#000000' }}
          titleStyle = {{color : '#000000'}}
          navigationBarStyle = {{backgroundColor : '#ffc60a'}}
          backButtonTintColor = '#000'
          leftButtonStyle = {{color : '#000',tintColor : '#000'}}
          //hideNavBar={true}
        />
```